# Error installing packages or updating due to dpkg: error processing linux-image-extra-3.11.0-15-generic

Tags: 13.10, dpkg

A few days back I tried to install 0ad, a game, through the terminal. I accidentally closed the terminal before it was finished and now I can't install or update any program on my machine. I'm running 13.10.

I have tried searching and found many articles, posts, and discussions around this error but I have yet to find a method that works to fix it.

I have tried running

```
sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoremove
```

which outputs

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-headers-3.11.0-12 linux-headers-3.11.0-12-generic linux-image-3.11.0-12-generic linux-image-extra-3.11.0-12-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 4 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
7 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 210 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
(Reading database ... 315931 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-headers-3.11.0-12-generic ...
Removing linux-headers-3.11.0-12 ...
Removing linux-image-extra-3.11.0-12-generic ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.11.0-12-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-12-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-12-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.11.0-12-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-12-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 35: /etc/default/grub: Syntax error: EOF in backquote substitution
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 2
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postrm.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-extra-3.11.0-12-generic.postrm line 328.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-extra-3.11.0-12-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing linux-image-3.11.0-12-generic ...
Examining /etc/kernel/prerm.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/prerm.d/dkms 3.11.0-12-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-12-generic
dkms: removing: bbswitch 0.7 (3.11.0-12-generic) (i686)

-------- Uninstall Beginning --------
Module:  bbswitch
Version: 0.7
Kernel:  3.11.0-12-generic (i686)
-------------------------------------

Status: Before uninstall, this module version was ACTIVE on this kernel.

bbswitch.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/3.11.0-12-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.

depmod.....

DKMS: uninstall completed.
dkms: removing: nvidia-319-updates 319.60 (3.11.0-12-generic) (i686)

-------- Uninstall Beginning --------
Module:  nvidia-319-updates
Version: 319.60
Kernel:  3.11.0-12-generic (i686)
-------------------------------------

Status: Before uninstall, this module version was ACTIVE on this kernel.

nvidia_319_updates.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/3.11.0-12-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.

depmod....

DKMS: uninstall completed.
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.11.0-12-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-12-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-12-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.11.0-12-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-12-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 35: /etc/default/grub: Syntax error: EOF in backquote substitution
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 2
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postrm.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.11.0-12-generic.postrm line 328.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-3.11.0-12-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-3.11.0-12-generic
 linux-image-3.11.0-12-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Then I also tried running

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

which outputs

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-3.11.0-15-generic:
 linux-image-extra-3.11.0-15-generic depends on linux-image-3.11.0-15-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.11.0-15-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing linux-image-extra-3.11.0-15-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up linux-image-3.11.0-17-generic (3.11.0-17.31) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.11.0-17-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-17-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 3.11.0-17-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-17-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.11.0-17-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-17-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-17-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 3.11.0-17-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-17-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 3.11.0-17-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-17-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 3.11.0-17-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-17-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 35: /etc/default/grub: Syntax error: EOF in backquote substitution
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 2
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.11.0-17-generic.postinst line 1010.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-3.11.0-17-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-3.11.0-17-generic:
 linux-image-extra-3.11.0-17-generic depends on linux-image-3.11.0-17-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.11.0-17-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing linux-image-extra-3.11.0-17-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic:
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-3.11.0-17-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.11.0-17-generic is not configured yet.
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-extra-3.11.0-17-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-extra-3.11.0-17-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing linux-image-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-image-generic (= 3.11.0.17.18); however:
  Package linux-image-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic-pae:
 linux-generic-pae depends on linux-generic (= 3.11.0.17.18); however:
  Package linux-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing linux-generic-pae (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-3.11.0-15-generic
 linux-image-3.11.0-17-generic
 linux-image-extra-3.11.0-17-generic
 linux-image-generic
 linux-generic
 linux-generic-pae
```

I'm at a loss and do not know where to go from here.

Any help you could provide will be greatly appreciated.

The output of

```
uname -r
```

is

```
3.11.0-15-generic
```

**EDIT**

I ran

```
sudo dpkg -P linux-image-3.11.0-12-generic
```

and got output

```
(Reading database ... 286111 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-3.11.0-12-generic ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.11.0-12-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-12-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-12-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.11.0-12-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-12-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 35: /etc/default/grub: Syntax error: EOF in backquote substitution
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 2
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postrm.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.11.0-12-generic.postrm line 328.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-3.11.0-12-generic (--purge):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-3.11.0-12-generic
```

I then ran

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

and got output

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-3.11.0-12-generic linux-image-extra-3.11.0-12-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
9 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 136 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
(Reading database ... 286111 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-extra-3.11.0-12-generic ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.11.0-12-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-12-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-12-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.11.0-12-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-12-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 35: /etc/default/grub: Syntax error: EOF in backquote substitution
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 2
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postrm.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-extra-3.11.0-12-generic.postrm line 328.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-extra-3.11.0-12-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing linux-image-3.11.0-12-generic ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.11.0-12-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-12-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-12-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.11.0-12-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-12-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 35: /etc/default/grub: Syntax error: EOF in backquote substitution
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 2
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postrm.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.11.0-12-generic.postrm line 328.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-3.11.0-12-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-3.11.0-12-generic
 linux-image-3.11.0-12-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Try `sudo dpkg -P linux-image-3.11.0-12-generic` and run `sudo apt-get install -f` .Finally post the second command output in your question.

Comment: I lost my network connection after this. I thinks some one screwed up note the "vmlinuz" instead of vmlinux.

Comment: A link to understanding vmlinuz; [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vmlinux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vmlinux) . Vmlinuz not an error or typo.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty self-explanatory:

```
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 35: /etc/default/grub: Syntax error: EOF in backquote substitution
```

You have an error in your `/etc/default/grub`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be related to debconf database corruption.
Run the following:

```
sudo /usr/share/debconf/fix_db.pl
```

You might have fixed the problem right there.
Check to see if any of these templates were effected by running the following bash commands:

```
diff -u /var/cache/debconf/config.dat{-old,}    | grep ^[+-]Name
diff -u /var/cache/debconf/templates.dat{-old,} | grep ^[+-]Name
```

You may sill want to run the following command on the package that was causing trouble:

```
 dpkg-reconfigure <your package>
```